# Creating a Hyperlink in a Comment Box

Tags: support, comment, markdown, hyperlinks

I am not sure if this has been asked before. Could anyone teach me how to create a hyperlink in a comment box? Posting URL's (especially those that are very long) seems to be a very ugly way of directing people to other websites. Thank you very much!

Comment: [How to format links in comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/how-to-format-links-in-comments),
[How do you cite a reference in a comment?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/how-do-you-cite-a-reference-in-a-comment)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The format is `[name](url)`, for example [Google](http://google.com). Be sure to include http:// in the URL, or it won't work.

Comment: Thank you very much, Pavel!